Как вернуть закрытую вкладку Folder в VS Code
Я случайно закрыл вкладку Folder в VS code и не знаю как открыть ее обратно немного посмотрев в интернете не нашел

Кликни правой кнопкой мыши по этому сайдбару слева и поставь галочку на "Проводник".
